# setSerializationId no such method error

Tags: java, spring, nosuchmethoderror

Im trying to run my project, but this error hits me everytime:

```
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.setSerializationId(Ljava/lang/String;)V 
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467) 
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397) 
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
```

This is my spring application context:

http://sharetext.org/2E7

What can cause this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using? Is it possible that you have two version of Spring in your classpath at the same time?

Comment: Im trying to upgrade my spring version to 3.0.5 and i was using 2.5. I excluded my ex spring 2.5 jars but still getting this error.

Comment: Have you solved? Have you checked your jars as I've suggested?

Comment: Yes i solved şt but i didnt understand how i did it. Thanks for the answers :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `setSerializationId` method is present in `DefaultListableBeanFactory` class from spring 3.0 but not in the same class from spring 2.5. I think you're working with a mixdown of the two versions of spring. It seems that you are using a library which depends on the old version of spring, for instance maybe spring-web. I suggest you to check all the jars in your classpath.